# probably wrong if statement, not moving to next row after input

Tags: c++, if-statement

When I run my program, I have to type how many rows do I want in my output. I have a limit from 1 to 100 rows. Each row is a task with a name of the task followed by increasing number, example: Task1:, Task2, .... When I type something into input, it must convert input string /see the code below - except the code in main();/.
My problem is that when I type first input, it should go to next task/next row/ but it doesnt. I type for example 10 strings but they dont go each to next task but they stay in one task..hope you understand now.

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include <ctype.h>

    using namespace std;

    void Convert(string input){
        string output = "";
        string flag = "";
        bool underscore = false;
        bool uppercase = false;
        if ( islower(input[0]) == false){
            cout << "Error!" <<endl;
            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++){
            if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || (input[i]) == '_') == false){
                cout << "Error!" <<endl;
                return;
            }
            if (islower(input[i])){
                if (underscore){
                    underscore = false;
                    output += toupper(input[i]);
                }
                else
                    output += input[i];

            }
            else if (isupper(input[i])){
                if (flag == "C" || uppercase){
                    cout << "Error!"<<endl;
                    return;
                }
                flag = "Java";
                output += '_';
                output += tolower(input[i]);

            }
            else if (input[i] == '_'){
                if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
                cout << "Error!" <<endl;
                return;
                }
                flag = "C";
                underscore = true;
            }
        }
        cout << output <<endl;
    } 



    int main(){

        const int max = 100;
        string input;
        int pocet_r;
        cout << "Zadaj pocet uloh:" << endl;
        cin >> pocet_r;

        if(pocet_r >= 1 && pocet_r <=100)
        {
                   for (int i = 0; i <pocet_r; i++)
                   {
                     cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl;
                     while (cin >> input)
                     Convert (input);



                    while(input.size() > max)
                     cout << "slovo musi mat minimalne 1 a maximalne 100 znakov" << endl;

                     while(input.size() > max)
                     cin >> input;


                    while (cin >> input)
                    Convert(input);



                   }
        }else{
         cout << "Minimalne 1 a maximalne 100 uloh" << endl;
    }


    system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: You should write more that one very long and hard to understand sentence and explain in detail what you are trying to do otherwise we won't be able to help and consequently you will be very frustrated because we won't help you at all so please rephrase your question so that we have a chance to understand it ! Am I clear ?

Comment: Convoluted and awkwardly deep indented. Won't read. Improve that, people won't invest time trying to guess what your problem is.

Comment: sorry fellas, I updated

Answer (score 0):

Your first if in Convert will always fail on a non-underscore and return.  I don't think that's what's intended.  Agree with other answer on the while cin loop.  The next two whiles should be if's apparently.  Step thru this code with a debugger and watch it line by line and see where it fails.  You've got multiple issues here, and I'm not entirely sure what the intent is.

Edit - I didn't parse the extra parenthesis correctly.  The first if in convert is actually okay.

Comment: More specifically, drop the while in `while (cin >> input)`.  The uppercase variable is never set true, but doesn't hurt anything since you also set flag to "C". If you have a task name with 2 underscores it will give an error.

Comment: I found out, that when I type something, I press enter and I get converted string which is perfect, then i do it one more time, I get same result. Now I have 4 lines of strings. Task1:input,output,input,output Task2: input, output, input,output Task3: input, .... wondering why?

Comment: Because you have 2 Convert( ) calls per loop.  Does that address your question?